# flatten output of convolution1dLayer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, flatten

This is the architecture of my layers for a problem in which I need to classify sequences into two separate classes. The flattenLayer implementation of Matlab does not perform the desired flattening as I hoped for. The input of the flattenLayer is 120(T)x1(B)x54(T), the output is the same. I actually want to have a 6480x1 output, so a flattening of the time dimension and the channel dimension. My custom defined layer is the following :

```
classdef CustomReshapeLayer < nnet.layer.Layer
    methods
        function layer = CustomReshapeLayer(name)
            layer.Name = name;
            layer.Description = "Custom reshape operation";
        end
        
        function Z = predict(~, X)
            [C,~,T] = size(X);
            Z = reshape(X, [C*T, 1]); 
            Z = squeeze(Z); 
        end
        
        function dLdX = backward(~, X, ~, dLdZ, ~)
            [C,~,T] = size(X);
            dLdZ = reshape(dLdZ, [C*T, 1]); 
            dLdX = reshape(dLdZ, [C, 1, T]); 
        end
    end
end
```

When outputing the dimensions of this layer, the dimensions are correct. But when analysing the network in the deep network analyser of Matlab the Time dimension is still there, resulting in a "  Network: Incompatible input and output sequence lengths. The network must
return sequences with the same length as the input data or data without a
time dimension."

```
layers = [
    sequenceInputLayer(15, 'Name', 'sequence','MinLength',140)
    convolution1dLayer(5, 20)
    reluLayer
    maxPooling1dLayer(3, 'Stride', 1)
    convolution1dLayer(5, 60)
    reluLayer
    maxPooling1dLayer(3, 'Stride', 2)
    convolution1dLayer(5, 120)
    convolution1dLayer(7, 120)
    %flattenLayer FlattenLayer of matlab
    %CustomReshapeLayer('flatten temporal') custom implementation
    fullyConnectedLayer(2000)
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(700)
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(50)
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(2)
    softmaxLayer
    %sigmoidLayer
    classificationLayer
];
```

Is there any way to obtain the desired flattening operation? The Python code on which my network is based is the following:

```
def model_define():
  model=Sequential()
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=5, activation='relu',input_shape=(651,6)))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides = 3))
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=60, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
  #model.add(Dropout(0.7))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides = 5))
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=120, kernel_size=5,))
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=120,kernel_size=7,))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(2000, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(700, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
  return model
```

Thanks in advance.